# Right shift operator in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

I got the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c = 128;

    c = c >> 1;

    printf("c = %d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Running the above code on [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) 32 bit, I got the result: `-64`. Why `-64`?

Comment: Hint: After the line `char c = 128;` add the line `printf("before shift c = %d\n", c);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the `char` type is a signed 8-bit integer (in the implementation of C that you are using). If you try to store the value 128 in it, it will actually be -128.

The bits for that would be:

```
10000000
```

Shifting a negative number will keep the sign bit set (as your implementation uses an arithmetic shift):

```
11000000
```

The result is -64.

Comment: +1.  But you should clarify that `char` is signed **on that particular platform**.  Also, you should clarify that the standard doesn't specify any particular behaviour for right-shifting negative values.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, you are right. This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B has specific information about what's in the standard regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard doesn't specify whether char is signed or unsigned. In this case it looks like you're getting a signed char, with a range from -128 to +127. Assigning 128 to it rolls round and leaves you with -128, so c>>1 is -64.

If you specify c as "unsigned char", c>>1 will be 64.

As the comment says, right-shifting a negative value is undefined by the standard so it's just luck that it comes out as -64.

Comment: +1 for the first part.  But you should clarify that right-shifting negative values is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `c` is signed. Changing the declaration to `unsigned char c`... will yield a result of 64.

Answer (score 0):

You are using type `char` which by default is signed. Signed `char`s have a range of -128 to 127. which means char c = 128 really sets `c` to -128. (This is because most processors use two's complement to represent negative numbers) Thus when you shift right you get -64.

Bottom line is that when doing bit manipulations, use unsigned types to get the results you expect.

Comment: Re *"by default is signed"*: No, it depends. For an IBM C++ compiler for [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX), it turned out to be different from all other environments encountered up until that point (a cross-platform C++ application). It was the only change required, though.